# Update an entire database avoiding Foreign and Primary Key constrants errors

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a running database on customer's server, and production database on my PC. As usual, production DB is updated as I develop with new fields and records.

I need the entire production DB (including estructure and records) to be replaced with customer's server existing DB.

When I export production DB and try to import on cutomer's server, I get

```
Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

This is expected: If there's an existing primary 1 ID, it is normal that PHPmyAdmin avoids me replacing it. So I try to TRUNCATE or DROP this table, in order to re-import it fully again. When I try to do this, this (also expected) error emerges, avoiding me to remove FK fields:

```
#1701 - Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key
constraint (`waisap_db`.`ws_stdmessages`, CONSTRAINT
`ws_stdmessages_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sm_fk_us_id`) REFERENCES
`waisap_db`.`ws_users` (`us_id`))
```

How could I update entire DB? Which option whould I choose when exporting development DB?

Comment: Do a backup and restore. Apply new changes to restored database by running alter table scripts.

Comment: @Namphibian my SQL exported from production DB already includes ALTER statements, such as this: ALTER TABLE `ws_stdmessages`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ws_stdmessages_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sm_fk_us_id`) REFERENCES `ws_users` (`us_id`);

Comment: Is this what you were recommending me? It already has them and error remains

Comment: Did you do a full backup and restore? The full procedure will essentially drop your database and recreate all the objects. Sounds like you did a data export and import which is NOT the same as a full backup and restore cycle.

Comment: No I did not. I'll try in an hour, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; before importing and then set it back to 1 after to avoid foreign key constraints error.